# How to install a Brother HL2270dw laser printer?

Tags: software-installation, brother

How can I install my Brother HL2270dw laser printer? There are no drivers available in the Software Center.

Comment: A Linux driver installer can now be found at http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2270dw_all

Answer (score 38):

1. Open a terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Download the driver installation script:

   ```
    wget https://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.3-1.gz
   ```
3. Unzip it:

   ```
    gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.3-1.gz
   ```
4. Run it as root:

   ```
    sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.3-1
   ```
5. Enter `HL2270-DW` as "model name", then `y` to continue
6. When asked "Will you specify the DeviceURI?" choose "No" for USB connection or "Yes" for network connection.
7. If you selected "Yes" for network connection, you'll be prompted to `select the number of destination Device URI.`. Look for the option `(I): Specify IP address.` and type the number shown before it.
8. Enter the permanent IP address of your printer (you may need to configure your router or DNS server to ensure that the printer is always assigned the same IP).

Comment: I tested this on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 and it works great.

Comment: The instructions in this answer work, and are consistent with the  instructions from the [brother website](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2270dw_all) , although the version numbers may change if brother updates the script from their end.

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me.  What should I do when I get to: `select the number of destination Device URI`?

Comment: Ah, and you can press 3 times within 2 seconds the "Go" button to get a printout of your setting. In case you need the IP address.

Comment: Thank you this saved me on Ubuntu 16. Not sure why this wasn't accepted by OP.

Comment: These instructions does not work for me anymore since the URLs seems to have changed but this worked for me: `wget https://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1.gz`, then `gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1.gz` and then `sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1`

Proceed as from step 5 in the original instructions.

Comment: New driver script link as of July 29, 2021 is `https://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-2.gz`

Answer (score 1):

I have a blog post on how to install the printer for wireless wifi printing in Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. Note my version is specific and only tested for the 64 bit version of Ubuntu. Brother does not include 64 bit drivers for the HL-2270DW drivers but I have patched the drivers to make them work with the 64 bit version. The patched drivers give access to ALL the features of the printer. The link is http://chadchenault.blogspot.com/2012/05/brother-hl-2270dw-printer-driver.html

Steps:

1. Download patched drivers to work with 64 bit ubuntu from the link above. You can also patch them yourselves using the command line and instructions from Brother's website.
2. Open a terminal window "ctrl + alt + t"
3. change into the directory to where the files where downloaded
4. Enter the following two commands from the terminal window.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all hl2270dwlpr-2.1.0-1a.i386.deb<code>  
sudo dpkg -i --force-all cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4-2a.i386.deb<code>
```

USB printing should now work. If you want to configure wifi or ethernet printing, you will need to configure CUPS. I have instructions with pictures at my blog.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

i know a ton of people have had major issues getting this printer to work with both ubuntu and mint, so i thought i'd pass this along since it's pretty painless. i found the attached script (following the instructions) in an ubuntu forum somewhere (I forget exactly where) which worked for me on both Ubuntu 12.04 and Mint Cinnamon 13 (64-bit versions). as long as the printer is already on your network (i installed mine through my windows 7 partition), it should work. just copy and paste the code sample below into an empty text document and save it as PrinterInstall.sh .  Then run the application from the terminal with:

```
sudo ./PrinterInstall
```

It may tell you that you need `bsdtar` to run the script, just install that with:

```
sudo apt-get install bsdtar
```

and then run `./PrinterInstall` again.

The terminal will ask you where your init.d directory is -- just check the choices in your file browser to confirm one or the other.

Next, turn on the printer and run the following from the terminal:

```
system-config-printer
```

When the config GUI opens, right click on the printer and select 'properties'. Under the device URI, click 'change' --> network printer --> select first brother option --> apply

that's it!

script code below:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# Brother HL-2270DW printer install tested on arch and ubuntu 12.04
# https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=109570
# https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=285166#c12
# http://github.com/willejos/bash

[[ $UID -ne 0 ]] && echo "Must run as root" && exit 1

which bsdtar > /dev/null
if [ $? == 1 ]; then
  echo "you need to install bsdtar before running this script"
  exit 1;
fi

which perl > /dev/null
if [ $? == 1 ]; then
  echo "you need to install perl before running this script"
  exit 1;
fi

echo -e "\nMake sure cups is running before proceeding...\n"
read -p "Hit any button to continue." -n 1

echo -e "\n\nWhere's your init script directory?"
echo -e "1. /etc/init.d/\n2. /etc/rc.d/"
read -p "(Select 1 or 2): " INIT_DIR
while [[ $INIT_DIR != 1 && $INIT_DIR != 2 ]]; do
  read -p "Where's your init script directory? (choose 1 or 2): " INIT_DIR
done

START_DIR=$(pwd)
mkdir br_tmp && cd br_tmp
wget http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/hl2270dwlpr-2.1.0-1.i386.rpm
wget http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4-2.i386.rpm

if [[ ! -f hl2270dwlpr-2.1.0-1.i386.rpm || ! -f cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4-2.i386.rpm ]]; then
  echo -e "One or both files not found: \n  hl2270dwlpr-2.1.0-1.i386.rpm \n  cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4-2.i386.rpm \n\n Was there a problem with the download?"
  exit 1;
fi

# extract and check directories exist
bsdtar -xf hl2270dwlpr-2.1.0-1.i386.rpm
bsdtar -xf cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4-2.i386.rpm
HL_DIR=""$START_DIR"/br_tmp/usr/local/Brother/Printer/HL2270DW/inf/"
CUPS_DIR=""$START_DIR"/br_tmp/usr/local/Brother/Printer/HL2270DW/cupswrapper/"
if [[ ! -d "$HL_DIR" || ! -d "$CUPS_DIR" ]]; then
  echo "rpm extraction failed"
  exit 1
fi

# in-place edit files
cd "$HL_DIR"
perl -pi -e 's/printcap.local/printcap/g' setupPrintcap2
if [ "$INIT_DIR" == "2" ]; then
  cd "$CUPS_DIR"
  perl -pi -e 's/init.d/rc.d/g' cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4
fi

# copy files to system and install cupswrapper
cd "$START_DIR"/br_tmp/
cp -ri usr/* /usr/
cp -ri var/* /var/
cd ../ && rm -rf br_tmp

echo -e "If I hang here, be patient....\n"
/usr/local/Brother/Printer/HL2270DW/cupswrapper/cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4 || exit 1

echo -e "\nNext steps: "
echo "Make sure printer shows up in cups config @ http://127.0.0.1:631"
echo "Edit /etc/cups/printers.conf and change the DeviceURI from ‘usb:xxxxx’ to ‘file:///dev/usb/lp0′ (or usb/lp1 or whatever exists, no quotes)."
echo -e "Restart cups\n"
```

Comment: Not sure why but I still get this message after following your instructions. 'Processing - Unable to locate printer "BrotherWireless".' It quit working after I installed 13.10

Answer (score 1):

Eric Carvalho's answer worked fine, with one qualifier:  the download location didn't work for me.  Looks like maybe Brother reorganized their downloads.  My first step was to manually download, starting from Brother's support site:

--go to brother.com (for me, this redirects to brother-usa.com)
--click Support
--enter HL-2270DW in the model number, then click Search
--in Downloads and drivers, click on the 'downloads from our solutions center' 
--select the OS (linux) and the version (deb)
--click on the Driver install tool
--accept license agreement

This is a tiny file, so it'll take no noticeable time to download.

Now unzip and run the script as Mr. Carvalho indicated.  Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's waiting for you to `specify the Device URI?`, and offering to let you pick from the 11 ways it knows a printer *could* be connected. It thinks you will want choice `11 (A): Auto. (usb://dev/usblp0)`, so it has pre-filled the field, and is waiting for you to either hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept choice `11`, or to specify a choice of your own, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If your printer is connected via USB, `11 (A): Auto. (usb://dev/usblp0)` is the choice you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my install notes under 14.04 (64-bit). I don't know that all these steps are necessary. I installed it as a network printer.

I have run a script from Brother:
linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1

in the downloaded file:
linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
from support.brother.com. This seemed to run successfully and install various packages.

There are two more files on their website that I have downloaded:

- cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4-2a.i386.deb
- hl2270dwlpr-2.1.0-1a.i386.deb

I used synaptic to see if they have been installed by the script above.

cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4-2 shows up as being installed.

Used the software center to install the "a" version and the hl2270*a.i386.deb packages.

I installed it despite the software center warning that it was "of bad quality".

Rebooted computer and turned printer off/on.

Used System Settings>Printers>Add Printer>Network Printer

Clicking the Find button (with host blank) pulls up two Brother HL-2270DW, one has an IP address.

For this one the description says AppSocket/JetDirect network printer via DNS-SD

The other says LPD network printer with Host BRW008092BA5199 and Queue Binary_P1

I am trying the one with an ip address.
Now under printer drivers, I have HL-2270DW for CUPS which I did not have before.

Selecting this.
Test Page worked.

Answer (score 0):

These notes work with Kubuntu and Linux Mint 17.1.

Obtain the packages `brgenml1lpr-3.1.0-1.i386.deb` and `brgenml1cupswrapper-3.1.0-1.i386.deb` from 
http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2270dw_all&os=128

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-profiles lib32z1
sudo dpkg -i ~/packages/brother_printer/brgenml1lpr-3.1.0-1.i386.deb 
sudo dpkg -i ~/packages/brother_printer/brgenml1cupswrapper-3.1.0-1.i386.deb
```

now use the KDE or Mint/Gnome printer configuration window to delete the auto installed USB printer that does not exist, then install the HL-2270DW using the BrGenML1 driver.

The printer should be auto detected. If not try using the URI listed below.

set duplex DuplexNoTumble to print on both sides of the page, flipping on long edge

URI: lpd://(printer's IP address)/binary_p1

Answer (score 0):

I tried the instructions at the beginning of this post but when I got to the end, i.e. 
When asked "Will you specify the DeviceURI?" choose "No" for USB connection or "Yes" for network connection.
I was given a list of eleven URIs to choose from, none of which made any sense to me as a neophite Ubuntu users. See below:

```
Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->Y

0: socket
1: http
2: ipp
3: https
4: ipps
5: lpd
6: ipp14
7: hp
8: hpfax
9: smb
10 (I): Specify IP address.
11 (A): Auto. (usb://dev/usblp0)

select the number of destination Device URI. ->11
```

It seems these instructions ended in mid-stream and thus I'm not able to proceed.

Bob Thomson
Ottawa Canada