# Brother HL-2270DW Printer uninstalling after software update

Tags: 14.04, updates, printing, update-manager, brother

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and have a Brother HL-2270DW printer that I am trying to connect to my computer via USB. I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/226311/366573) to install the printer, and in general, it works fine. However, every time I get a software update, the printer uninstalls, and I have to re-run the installation script. Also, every time I get a software update, the printer settings in general reset (there are lots of WiFi connected printers around that I delete from my Printer Settings, only for them to all return when the update finishes). How can I keep this from continually happening every time something updates?

Thanks!

Edit:

Here's the output from the last time I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` and had the printer go away:

```
sabeek@sabeek-S400CA:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
[sudo] password for sabeek: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpio
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 73.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main cpio amd64 2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1 [73.3 kB]
Fetched 73.3 kB in 0s (153 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 576043 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cpio_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpio (2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) over (2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cpio (2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
```

Comment: Sounds like the installation script edits package owned files. I think you need to narrow down the problem a bit, since I assume that not each package update has the effect you describe. In other words you need to figure out which package(s) causes the printer to become "uninstalled" when it's updated.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The two packages that the script installs are hl2270dwlpr-2.1.0-1.i386.deb and cupswrapperHL2270DW-2.0.4-2.i386.deb. I don't know which, if any, get uninstalled when the software updater runs. How would I find that out?

Comment: So the script creates and installs .deb files? I didn't know that, but it might make it easier to spot the problem. One thing you could do next time the Software Updater prompts you to update, instead of confirming you could open a terminal window, run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and carefully notice what it outputs. It would be valuable if you edited your question and added the output from such a manual update to it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to do that. Since that'll probably be in a few days, do you think I'd be best off editing this question, replying here, or making a new question?

Comment: No need to submit a new question. Once you edit the question above, it will be noticed by those who follow new or modified questions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the fault you are experiencing is not solvable via Ubuntu tweaks but the fault of the Brother Driver programmers themselves.

I'm still new to this site, and I understand this site offers the ability to post personal views and advice.  Someday I hope to take advantage of these features to help new users to avoid these issues such as those you are having.

Certain printer manufacturers are much more supportive of linux, or of PC users in general.  Brother has an unfortunate history of drivers which uninstall even in Windows, and printers which seem to break themselves requiring frequent maintenance.

In recent years Canon, a once great printer manufacturer has taken to refusing to so much as provide drivers for Linux.

Meanwhile HP, Epson and even Brother at least provide Linux drivers, perfect or not.  I would really like to see a "recommended printers/brands list" on this site, perhaps with votes from other site members to assist people such as yourself to make wise decisions when buying.

At present I have an Epson wifi/ethernet network inkjet printer with fax ability and sheet feeder which cost only $80 new, model WF-2540.  Setting it up with Linux was a bit of a hassle at first but once it was configured it has been a dream.  Guests with macbooks were able to print to it with nothing more than the wifi password.  We are the envy of our friends.